# Cycle2 Slideshow Glitch Where Image Will Randomly Overlap with DIV Below

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-cycle2

On a recent project I'm running into an issue where an image in a Cycle2 slideshow will overlap on a div just below it.  It happens quite randomly (there are seven pages using this slideshow and it happens, oh, every 8th or 9th time — I haven't been able to spot the pattern.

When it happens, bringing up the web inspector will force a redraw and the image will pop into place. I have seen this in Safari, Firefox and Chrome and on both Mac and Windows.

A screen shot of the glitch is on Droplr and the live version is [here](http://seraformarch.com/projects/previous-work/columbia-river-crossing). It happens with all seven pages (found under the Seraform and Previous Work menus) and it might take several clicks through all pages to see the issue.

http://d.pr/i/wnwk

And this is how the page should look:

http://d.pr/i/esRS

I have tried every debugging trick I can think of and am at a complete loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I investigated the issue further, I found the problem was connected to the div holding the slides would always start with an area of 0 pixels. Most of the time, that div would resize automatically (pushing the other div down) but, on rare occasions, the block would stay 0 pixels causing and the image would overlap.

To solve this, I tossed in a redraw function I found on [Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/ahazha) as part of some JS to, well, redraw the slideshow area on document ready.